# Sorting list by date Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

My data is in the form:
`[{'value': 2, 'year': u'2015'}, {'value': 4, 'year': u'2016'}, {'value': 3, 'year': u'2018'}, {'value': 0, 'year': u'2014'}, {'value': 0, 'year': u'2017'}]`

I want to sort it by year. Can you please help?

Comment: Maybe the data structure you are using (list of dictionaries) is not adapted to whatever you want to achieve).

Comment: @Tarik, I don't think so, it is really doable. See my answer about `itemgetter`

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `key` function applied for comparing when sorting:

```
my_data = sorted( my_data, key = lambda x : x["year"])
```

Comment: The string comparison will break if you have a year like `987`.  You might want to use: `lambda x: int(x['year'])`

Comment: True, my code was specific to this data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `itemgetter` for that:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> data = [{'value': 2, 'year': u'2015'}, {'value': 4, 'year': u'2016'}, {'value': 3, 'year': u'2018'}, {'value': 0, 'year': u'2014'}, {'value': 0, 'year': u'2017'}]
>>> result = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('year'))
>>> print(result)
[{'value': 0, 'year': '2014'}, {'value': 2, 'year': '2015'}, {'value': 4, 'year': '2016'}, {'value': 0, 'year': '2017'}, {'value': 3, 'year': '2018'}]
```